# Why does my exe file not work properly even it runs well in codeblocks?

Tags: c, windows, codeblocks

Im practicing the C programming language. Im able to make a calculator program and it runs as intended in codeblocks. However, when I tried to locate the exe file i made from building the program from inside codeblocks(Ctrl + F9), the exe file shows the display but stops as soon as I enter a value after this line pops up "Enter operator (+, -, *, /): ". I tried restarting codeblocks. Any help?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int a;
int b;
int sum;
char op;
int difference;
int product;
double quotient;

int add(int a, int b){
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}


int subtract(int a, int b){
    difference = a-b;
    return difference;
}


int multiply(int a, int b){
    product = a*b;
    return product;
}


double divide(double a, double b){
    quotient = a/b;
    return quotient;
}


int main(){
    printf("Enter first number: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Enter operator (+, -, *, /): ");
    scanf(" %c",&op);

    if(op=='+'){
        printf("Sum is %d",add(a,b));
    }

    else if(op=='-'){
        printf("Difference is %d",subtract(a,b));
    }

    else if(op=='*'){
        printf("Product is %d",multiply(a,b));
    }

    else if(op=='/'){
        printf("Quotient is %f",divide(a,b));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say that the program "stops", do you mean that its window closes? As opposed, say, to it freezing and not accepting input?  If you mean that the window closes then are you sure it does so *before* you enter an operator?

Comment: If you open an interactive cmd.exe window and run your program within then does it exhibit different behavior?

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no reason to have *any* of the variables to be global. `op` is local to `main`, and the `sum` and other "result-holding" variables should belong to corresponding functions. Also you might want to learn about `switch/case` statement.

Comment: Yes, the window closes after I press enter after selecting the operator. You guys have been very helpful. I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I havent reached the switch/case statements so everything in that code is what Ive learned in C so far. Thanks for the comment, would read more about C

Comment: Your code does not compile because the variables `a` and `b` are not declared.

Answer (score 0):

After you entered the operator your program does its thing and then it hits return in the main function. This means it will shutdown the program. You can add a getchar() statement before the return This will keep the program "alive" until you press a button:

```
printf("Press any button to close\n");
getchar();
```